# Strange behavior when checking for Null values in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, phone-number

I am having an issue with filtering out phone numbers which have no value in them ie:

```
(___) ___ - ____
```

I tried this in my WHERE clause to get ALL the values that had a full phone number:

```
WHERE WRT_Phone <> null;
```

This allowed me to get all the phone numbers that had a full value in them.  But, when I attempt

```
WHERE WRT_Phone = null;
```

Nothing gets populated in the resulting table.  Are there any functions that I can use to turn the area code into a number or a function to check if phone number data type is null?

Also, I am using Access 2010 for executing the SQL statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to check for nulls is:

```
WHERE WRT_Phone IS null;
```

Answer (score 2):

To check for nulls you need to use `IS NULL`:

```
WHERE WRT_Phone IS NULL
```

In fact, to check for not null, you should technically use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
WHERE WRT_Phone IS NOT NULL
```

Something frankly odd (unique to Access?) is happening here because you should not be getting any results with `WHERE WRT_Phone <> null` either.

---

Generally speaking, when `NULL` is present on either side of a boolean operator or as part of an expression, the whole thing evaluates to `NULL` (which is considered FALSE for the purposes of a WHERE clause):

- In a non-null record:

  - `WRT_Phone = NULL` expands to `'foobar' = NULL` *which equals NULL* -> no record returned
  - `WRT_Phone <> NULL` expands to `'foobar' <> NULL` *which equals NULL* -> no record returned
- Likewise, in a null record:

  - `WRT_Phone = NULL` expands to `NULL = NULL` *which equals NULL* -> no record returned
  - `WRT_Phone <> NULL` expands to `NULL <> NULL` *which equals NULL* -> no record returned